# Faces indexed by iOS/Android app are not detected by Android/iOS App - AWS Rekognition

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

So I have been working on a product (Android First and then iOS) for a long time that index faces of people using AWS Rekognition and when they are again scanned later, it identifies them. 
It's working great when I index a face from an Android device and then try to search it with an Android device. But if I try to search it later on iOS app, it doesn't find it. Same is the result if I go other way round. Index with iOS, search with Android, not found.
The collection ID is same while indexing and searching on both devices. I couldn't figure out how is it possible that a face indexed by one OS type, same region, same collection, couldn't be found while on other device.

If anyone here could try and help me with the issue, please do. I'll be really thankful.

Update 1: I have called "listCollections" function on both iOS and android apps. Both of them are showing different list of collections. This is the issue. But I can't figure our why it is happening. The identity pool and region is same on both of them.

Here is my Android Code to access Rekognition:

```
mCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        mContext,
        "us-east-2:xbxfxexf-x5x5-xax7-x9xf-x5x0xexfx1xb", // Identity pool ID
        Regions.US_EAST_2 // Region
);

mUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");

mAmazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(mCredentialsProvider);
mAmazonS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2));
mAmazonRekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(mCredentialsProvider);

if(!mAmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(mFacesBucket)) {
    mAmazonS3Client.createBucket(mFacesBucket);
}

Log.i(TAG, "Uploading image to S3 Bucket");
mAmazonS3Client.putObject(mFacesBucket, getS3ObjectName(), new File(data[0].toString()));
Log.i(TAG, "Image Uploaded");

Image image = new Image();
try {
    image.setBytes(ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.toByteArray(new File(data[0].toString()))));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.i(TAG, "Indexing image");
IndexFacesRequest indexFacesRequest =new IndexFacesRequest()
        .withCollectionId(mFacesCollection)
        .withImage(image)
        .withExternalImageId(mUUID)
        .withDetectionAttributes("ALL");

mAmazonRekognitionClient.indexFaces(indexFacesRequest);
```

Here is my iOS code to access Rekognition:

```
func uploadToCollection(img: UIImage)
    {
        let myIdentityPoolId="us-east-2:xbxfxexf-x5x5-xax7-x9xf-x5x0xexfx1xb"

        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast2, identityPoolId: myIdentityPoolId)
        //store photo in s3()
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast2, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
        rekognitionClient = AWSRekognition.default()

        guard let request = AWSRekognitionIndexFacesRequest() else
        {
            puts("Unable to initialize AWSRekognitionindexFaceRequest.")
            return
        }
        var go=false
        request.collectionId = "i_faces" + self.firebaseID.lowercased() //here iosCollection will be replaced by firebase Current UserID
        request.detectionAttributes = ["ALL", "DEFAULT"]
        request.externalImageId = self.UUID //this should be mUUID, passed as parameter to this function
        let sourceImage = img
        let image = AWSRekognitionImage()
        image!.bytes = sourceImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)
        request.image = image
        self.rekognitionClient.indexFaces(request) { (response:AWSRekognitionIndexFacesResponse?, error:Error?) in
            if error == nil
            {
                print("Upload to Collection Complete")
            }
            go=true
            return
        }
        while(go==false){}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem turned out to be much different and solution was rather very simple. I posted another question regarding the same problem when I found it was a bit different and I have posted an answer as well. 
Here it is: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53128777/4395264

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection and added images to the collection and create an index. I suspect few things in your setup and code.

1) The Identity Pool Id, AWS Region used across iOS and Android

2) The name of the collection used (pay attention to the delimiters used in the collection name)

Android:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(appContext, "MyPoolID", Regions.US_EAST_1);

public void searchFacesByImage() {
        Image source = new Image().withS3Object(new S3Object().withBucket("us-east-1-bucket").withName("ms.jpg"));
        Image ms2 = new Image().withS3Object(new S3Object().withBucket("us-east-1-bucket").withName("ms-2.jpg"));
        Image ms3 = new Image().withS3Object(new S3Object().withBucket("us-east-1-bucket").withName("ms-3.jpg"));
        Image ms4 = new Image().withS3Object(new S3Object().withBucket("us-east-1-bucket").withName("ms-4.jpg"));

        String collectionId = "MyCollectionID";
        AmazonRekognitionClient client = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider);

        try {
            System.out.println("Creating collection: " + collectionId );
            CreateCollectionRequest request = new CreateCollectionRequest().withCollectionId(collectionId);
            CreateCollectionResult createCollectionResult = client.createCollection(request);
            System.out.println("CollectionArn : " + createCollectionResult.getCollectionArn());
            System.out.println("Status code : " + createCollectionResult.getStatusCode().toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        IndexFacesRequest indexFacesRequest = new IndexFacesRequest();
        indexFacesRequest.setImage(source);
        indexFacesRequest.setCollectionId(collectionId);
        client.indexFaces(indexFacesRequest);

        indexFacesRequest = new IndexFacesRequest();
        indexFacesRequest.setImage(ms2);
        indexFacesRequest.setCollectionId(collectionId);
        client.indexFaces(indexFacesRequest);

        indexFacesRequest = new IndexFacesRequest();
        indexFacesRequest.setImage(ms4);
        indexFacesRequest.setCollectionId(collectionId);
        client.indexFaces(indexFacesRequest);

        SearchFacesByImageRequest searchFacesByImageRequest = new SearchFacesByImageRequest();
        searchFacesByImageRequest
                .withCollectionId(collectionId)
                .withImage(ms3)
                .withFaceMatchThreshold(80F);

        SearchFacesByImageResult searchFacesByImageResult =
                client.searchFacesByImage(searchFacesByImageRequest);

        List <FaceMatch> faceImageMatches = searchFacesByImageResult.getFaceMatches();
        for (FaceMatch face: faceImageMatches) {
            Log.d(TAG, face.toString());
        }
    }
```

iOS:

Create the Cognito Credentials Provider

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1                                                                                                        identityPoolId: @"MyPoolID"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1                                                                          credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Use the same Identity Pool Id and Region (us-east-1).

```
func faceIndexNoFacesSearch() {
    let rekognition = AWSRekognition.default()
    let faceRequest = AWSRekognitionSearchFacesByImageRequest()
    do {
        let image = AWSRekognitionImage()
        image?.s3Object = AWSRekognitionS3Object()
        image?.s3Object?.bucket = "us-east-1-bucket"
        image?.s3Object?.name = "ms-2.jpg"
        faceRequest!.image = image
        faceRequest!.collectionId = "MyCollectionID"

        rekognition.searchFaces(byImage: faceRequest!).continueWith { (response) -> Any? in
            XCTAssertNil(response.error)
            XCTAssertNotNil(response.result)
            if let result = response.result {
                XCTAssertNotNil(result.faceMatches)
            }
            return nil
            }.waitUntilFinished()

    } catch  {
        print("exception")
    }
}
```

Please post questions in the comment and we can discuss there.

Comment: I have cross checked regions and identity pool IDs many times in both Android and iOS. They are exact same. The region is us-east-2.
The collection name is exact same too.
When I call listCollections function on android and iOS, they both show different list of collections. (I created a test collections on iOS and a test collection on android (different names) and they are not show in result of listCollections function.

Comment: Can you post the complete code snippet you have on iOS?

Comment: I have updated code snippets for both android and iOS. 
Android function basically index a face to collection and upload image to S3 bucket. The iOS function however just index face to collection. The S3 logic is implemented separately but that's not of our concern right now. I have checked and images from both iOS and android and going to correct directory in S3.